# Convert a specific column to lower case in a CSV file

Tags: perl, shell, csv

I've a CSV file and I want to convert a specific column to lower case. What is the efficient way of doing this in linux?

Comment: Probably something using [Text::CSV_XS](https://metacpan.org/module/Text::CSV_XS).

Comment: Please be aware that there are a large number of slightly incompatible CSV formats, because there are a large number of ways to answer yes or no to the following questions: Do double quotes enable commas to be quoted? If quotes are permitted, must the entire field be quoted? Can you include a double quote character by preceding it with a backslash? What about preceding it by a second double quote character? Can a double-quoted string contain a newline? Do backslashes also escape other characters, such as newline, comma or backslash itself? Etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
awk -F"," 'BEGIN{OFS=","} {$5 = tolower($5); print}' file
```

to change the 5th field.

There's also `-v OFS=","`, but not 100% sure how standard it is; also, quotes around `,` could be left out, but I kept them in for generality's sake; so, as a variant:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{$5 = tolower($5); print}' file
```

Note that awk fields are 1-based. sarathi's answer does the same thing in perl, which is 0-based; make sure you choose the right index.

EDIT: as melpomene rightly notes, both cases only work for simple CSV without quotes or escapes.

Comment: Fails on stuff like `foo,"bar,bar","baz""",quux`.

Comment: Sorry to revive such an old topic, but I ran this and it prints all the lines of the specified column in lowercase, but when I read the file the column is still in uppercase. How can I save it to the same file? (or get the file actually modified). Sorry for the question, I'm new to linux.

Comment: @PedroPabloSeverinHonorato You would typically redirect it into another file (`awk ... > newfile`); then you can overwrite the original (`mv newfile file`).

Comment: Ohh I see. Thank you @Amadan. And how would the command be if I want to change more than 1 column at the same time?

Comment: @PedroPabloSeverinHonorato `... '{$5 = tolower($5); $7 = tolower($7); print}' ...`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to convert colum3 to lower case for example:

```
perl -F -lane '$F[2]=lc($F[2]);print "@F"' your_file
```